# How to choose which function to call from two functions on a single touch event based on the time user has touched an object in corona sdk

Tags: iphone, lua, coronasdk

I am creating an object i want it to make it draggable when i apply touch event on it, and if 
user touches that object for more than 5 sec then that object must not work as draggable object but 
then i have to call some other function, after that i want to clear the counter so that after next touch it will be reinitialized..... how can it be achieved in corona i was trying this with Timer = os.time() but could not get the perfect result. Please suggest any idea... thanks

```
local function callfunc( event )
    local phase = event.phase
      if "began" == phase then
         Timer = os.time()
      if Timer>5 then
         func1()
        else
         func2()
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch",callfunc)
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming that you cannot get what you achieve because you did not remove the listener when going to another function see my code as a reference:

```
local function func1()

--set the object as draggable 

end

local function func2()
--remove the listener of the func1() and set another listener here
--call other function here

end

local function callfunc( event )
    local phase = event.phase
      if "began" == phase then
         Timer = os.time()
      if Timer>5 then
         func1()
        else
         func2()
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch",callfunc)
```

you can post another snippet of your code where the problem occurs if the idea above does't work since i only assume the problem that you have encountered. its hard to point out where the problem occur if there is only a snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

The event table passed on touch events has the time the event happened.  I would on the began phase, store the event.time.  Then when you get your first moved phase, if the time is over 5 seconds behave one way, else behave the other.